# Woocommerce digital download not working - database error Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm having an issue when trying to download a digital product from Woocommerce. When clicking the download link/button on thank you page or woocommerce email, the link shows an error.

After going to the PHP Error logs I found this:
WordPress database error Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.  CONSTRAINT fk_wc_download_log_permission_id FOREIGN KEY (permission_id)

REFERENCES wpdev_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions (permission_id) for query INSERT INTOwp01_wc_download_log`

How can I solve this?

Comment: WooCommerce and other 3rd party plugins are off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their communities. As a side-note, where you directed here by their support?

Comment: Related: https://jeffkaiser.com/downloads-working-again/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to your database, drop table ending with "wc_download_log" (it might have a prefix).
After droping the table deactivate Woocommerce and activate it again.

That will solve the trick. Just be careful, drop just that table, be sure to back things up first.

This post helped me solved this: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/unable-to-insert-download-log-entry-in-database/page/2/#post-13359528

Comment: Thanks a lot. Did just that and it worked for me. Thanks a whole lot